# Architecture of app which use C2DM and installed on several Android phones

Tags: android, architecture, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am developing Android app for a company which has **thousands of Employees** and all of them will use this app and company will be able to track all employees through the app.

One feature of my app is to **send data from Server to Android**. For this i am using **C2DM**. Since **C2DM require active Gmail account on each device** so all of the employees **need to create Gmail account for them and sign in to that account to use my app**(this is my understanding of problem) but my Client (Company Manager) dont want to let this to employees to create Gmail account for them.

In your opinion what should be best for me. do i continue to develop in C2DM or should i use some other mechanism ?

I am stuck in this problem
any help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before you go too far, please note that C2DM service is not for sending "data" to client/phone. Its meant for notifications. They payload is limited 1024 bytes. When you receive a notification, you should then establish a connection with your server and pull the data.

If your organization is using Google Apps, the domain administrator can programmatically provision accounts for all the users.

Comment: What Anirudh said.  An Android device without a Google account is sort of like a bicycle without tires, anyway.  You can use it, but it's going to be a rough ride.

Comment: @Anirudh. Thanks for ur answer. i was sure about payload limit. Beside as Sparky say **An Android device without a Google account is sort of like a bicycle without tires** this mean i dont need to bother about the Gmail account for each device.